# Problems with custom layout for AlertDialog

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to create an AlertDialog with a custom layout. The problem comes when I try to dismiss the dialog from an inner button, so I declare it final before. It's throwing an error saying that the custom layoutelement are null although the elements ids are properly referenced. Here is the code:

```
Context ctx = MyActivity.this;
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService( ctx.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mkdialog_layout, null);
builder.setView(dialogView);
final AlertDialog myalertdialog = builder.create();
Button okbtt = (Button)myalertdialog.findViewById(R.id.mkdialog_okbtt);
Button cancelbtt = (Button)myalertdialog.findViewById(R.id.mkdialog_cancelbtt);
TextView title = (TextView)myalertdialog.findViewById(R.id.mkdialog_titletv);
title.setText("Are you sure you want to log out?");
okbtt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
  public void onClick(View id) {
                        myalertdialog.dismiss();                        
                        Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                }});
cancelbtt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(View id) {
                        myalertdialog.dismiss();
                    }});
myalertdialog.show();
```

The error:

```
Process: com.mk.companionapp, PID: 22045 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at com.mk.companionapp.activities.ConfigurationActivity$2.onClick(ConfigurationActivity.java:185)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update your dialog code with this.

```
Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService( ctx.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mkdialog_layout, null);
builder.setView(dialogView);
final AlertDialog myalertdialog = builder.create();
Button okbtt = (Button)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.mkdialog_okbtt);
Button cancelbtt = (Button)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.mkdialog_cancelbtt);
TextView title = (TextView)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.mkdialog_titletv);
title.setText("Are you sure you want to log out?");
okbtt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
  public void onClick(View id) {
                        myalertdialog.dismiss();                        
                        Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                }});
cancelbtt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(View id) {
                        myalertdialog.dismiss();
                    }});
myalertdialog.show();
```

you initialized the view_items with wrong view.

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed the problem.

Comment: @Burakito accept it as an answer if it resolved your issue

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `myalertdialog` you should use `dialogView`. So to get your code working you have to replace

```
TextView title = (TextView)myalertdialog.findViewById(R.id.mkdialog_titletv);
```

with the following

```
TextView title = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.mkdialog_titletv);
```

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As others said use dialogView to find views instead of myalertdialog and also **pass Activity Context to Dialog not the Application context**. So make following Changes.

Context ctx = **YourActivity.this;**

TextView title = (TextView)myalertdialog.findViewById(R.id.mkdialog_titletv);

to

TextView title = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.mkdialog_titletv);

Answer (score 1):

Use this. You have to use Activity for creating AlertDialog.
Don't used ApplicationContext

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

Comment: Yes, I realized about that error when I solved the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

`TextView title = (TextView)myalertdialog.findViewById(R.id.mkdialog_titletv);`

to

`TextView title = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.mkdialog_titletv);`

Answer (score 0):

Using the following way will prevent Alert from closing as soon as we click on any button and gives us the option to close according to our business logic.

Below sample alert is having text and `EditText` as well in `custom_dialog`

```
        final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
        dialog.setView(dialogView);
        final EditText edt = (EditText)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.email_forgot);
        dialog.setView(dialogView);
        dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
            }
        });
        dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog forgotAlertDialog = dialog.create();
        forgotAlertDialog.show();
        forgotAlertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                //your positive action
            }
        });
```

To close the alert do the following according to logic

```
if (forgotAlertDialog.isShowing()) {
     forgotAlertDialog.dismiss();
}
```